# Graphs and trees

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I have came across a problem that deals with finding out the number of paths for all pairs of node which will be having edge 'E'. Formally, given a tree with 'N' nodes, and 'N-1' edges are given, then we need to find out the number of paths for all pairs of nodes which will be having edge "E".

I approached this problem, by deleting the given edge and then finding out the number of nodes in each component and the product of nodes in each component will provide the required answer.

I am removing each edge and then checking out the number of nodes in each component, so this is giving quadratic time. Can someone suggest a better way to approach this problem ?

Comment: have you tried Googling it? Ref : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Comment: @roottraveller i needed to solve this problem in O(n) , the approach i m doing solves it in O(n^2) . Floyd warshall algorithm will only increase the time complexity.

Comment: You first talk about a single edge E, but then say you are removing *each* edge.  Why don't you simply remove the single edge E, to get a linear-time solution?

Comment: we have to give answer after removing each edge.

Comment: This is not at all clear from your problem statement.  Please edit.